# Convert value to string object for property binding

Tags: angular, property-binding

I have a component to create my form dynamically, so I get all the metadata from the server and I have in my template a ngFor to create my fields. The attributes are all property bind with the result of the data that came from the server. In one of them I have the following situation:
if hard code like this 
`[filterParams]="{state:model.state_field}"`
when I call service, I can use this filterParams as an Object and send over the http request, but I as use the metadata from the server I actually code like this 
`[filterParams]="metadata.filterParams"`
and inside the metadata.filterParams I have the string "{state:model.state}", but the value for 'state' can't be a string because I use the model value.

How can I convert the string that comes from my metadata to an Object that catches the value from the model, just the way it works when hardcoded?

Comment: `console.log(metadata)` and show the output

Comment: I changed the names to ask the question, but at metadata.filterParams I have the value `metadata.filterParams: "{state:model.state_field}"`

I also updated the question.

Comment: Within quotes? `""`?

Comment: yes, because it comes from a json return. I tried to return as a json object but when I realized that hardcoding in the `[filterParams]` with `"{state:model.state_field}"` made the filter work I changed the return to a string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `metadata.filterParams: "{state:model.state_field}"` **to** `metadata.filterParams: {state:model.state_field}`

So try like this:

```
 yourFunction() {
    let model = {
      state_field: 1
    };
    var eventstring = this.metadata.filterParams.replace(/"/g, "");
    this.metadata.filterParams = eval(eventstring)
    console.log(this.metadata);
  }
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kuihjz)**

From your comment :  *when I realized that hardcoding in the [filterParams] with "{state:model.state_field}"*

Here : `[filterParams]="{state:model.state_field}"`

`""` isn't a string, quotes is used just to bind the object `{state:model.state_field}`

Comment: It's not what I trying to do. I really need to make `[filterParams]` to have the value `"{state : model.state_field}"` (with double quotes) with the value received from the metadata, because every request to my endpoint it will get the value of state_field from the model and will transform into a querystring like `state=NY` or `state=FL` if change the state.
I'm using a framework that creates the fields to me so I need to pass the value of the filter this way.

Comment: @Adrita in your example, after the last console.log() if you do
`model.state_field = 2;`
`console.log(this.metadata);`
the value remains 1

Comment: Yes that is obvious as the string is already evaluated before that

Comment: I'm using the library called Portinari UI ([link](http://portinari.io)) and my question is related to the component called lookup. Even I can see their source code, I don't know to pass the filter expression.